# Do Alzheimer's patients have spaces in their brain with low interstitial space?

Tags: alzheimer

Lulu Xie et al write in their paper [Sleep Drives Metabolite Clearance from the Adult Brain](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/342/6156/373):

> Using real-time assessments of tetramethylammonium diffusion and two-photon imaging in live mice, we show that natural sleep or anesthesia are associated with a 60% increase in the interstitial space, resulting in a striking increase in convective exchange of cerebrospinal fluid with interstitial fluid. In turn, convective fluxes of interstitial fluid increased the rate of β-amyloid clearance during sleep.

Given that Alzheimer's patients have more β-amyloid in their brains, do they also have less interstitial space?

Comment: I think the biology SE is better suited for this question